# self.variable.function() meaning in python or accessing a method through a class self variable

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I was reading this simple approach of a Binary Search tree insertion, below is the solution :

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.data = data

    def insert(self, data):
        if self.data:


            if data < self.data:
                if self.left is None:
                    self.left = Node(data)
                else:
                    self.left.insert(data)
            elif data > self.data:
                if self.right is None:
                    self.right = Node(data)
                else:
                    self.right.insert(data)
            else:
                self.data = data

    def PrintTree(self):
        if self.left:
            self.left.PrintTree()
        print(self.data),
        if self.right:
            self.right.PrintTree()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Node(12)
    root.insert(6)
    root.insert(14)
    root.insert(3)

    root.PrintTree()
```

But am still wondering on the following lines where they called a function through a variable :

```
self.left.insert(data)
```

then  :

```
self.right.insert(data)
```

and :

```
self.left.PrintTree()
```

What is this called ? I need a recap on this.

Comment: They are all just method invocations, where the object invoking the method is an attribute of an instance of `Node`.

Comment: Thanks @chepner, for the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the `insert(self, data)` method's content, the `right` and `left` instance attributes are meant to hold objects of type `Node`, which are references to the two child nodes of the `self` node. The lines you quoted call the methods defined in this very class, but instead of calling them on the `self` instance, they call them on the child nodes, so they'll be working with different data.

Comment: It makes sense, thanks so much Adam